# ag-grid-enterprice Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, react-redux, ag-grid

I work at React-Redux project.
I use ag-grid and have problems.

I get at console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at __extends (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13399), <anonymous>:8:9)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13399), <anonymous>:28:5)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13399), <anonymous>:301:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:13399)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
at fn (bundle.js:87)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13390), <anonymous>:14:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:13390)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
at fn (bundle.js:87)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13255), <anonymous>:10:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:13255)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
at fn (bundle.js:87)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:13246), <anonymous>:1:1)
```

Any solution?

Here is my packages.json relevant rows:

```
"ag-grid": "~7.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^14.2.0",
"ag-grid-react": "~7.1.0",
```

Comment: give an example to reproduce the error

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue.
But tried installing the same version of ag-grid-enterprise as that of ag-grid-react, then it worked.

```
"ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.3.0",
"ag-grid-react": "^25.3.0",
```

Hope it helps you! :)